# Fire+Smoke simulation won't refresh in Cycles

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

Smoke+fire animation won't update with edits, stuck on old version. It was updating correctly earlier. Now, no matter what changes I make or what I select or delete or reload or delete everything the old animation still plays in the 3D viewport. It's not baked.

The simulation is setup with a particle system as the flow source for fire + smoke and a smoke domain.

Could it be the cache or an artefact left in the animation editor? I'm out of ideas because I have little experience with the physics stuff. It could be cache related but unsure how to test.

[image: Particle system cache]

[image: Domain cache]

[image]

Comment: Are you re-caching the simulation every time you make a change? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We have no way to guess how you set up your project, the simulation, the emitter, the smoke domain, or textures, or render settings.

Comment: No I haven't touched the cache settings (above). The I'll post all relevant settings if the cache turns out not to be the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Re-caching meaning running the simulation again (alt+A). Are you doing that every time you make a change? Or press Free All Bakes and then Bake All Dynamics.

Comment: Yep I hit Alt+A repeatedly. I've had to move to a new blend file. The simulation animations just keep playing with Alt+A even after removing the flow source. I've freed the bakes. The Domain has somehow kept the sim and I don't know how to clear it. Please take a look at the blend file.